# locate cannot search /dev?

Tags: linux, find, locate

[image]

As the picture shows, I can use 'find' to search for a JPEG file in '/dev'. However, trying to do the same thing with 'locate' fails. It seems that 'locate' can search anywhere except '/dev' Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

`/dev` is for device files, not user files. As such, `updatedb` is told to not index anything in there, since users would not be storing files there.